# How would I go about plugging mongoengine into pyramid?

Tags: python, mongodb, pyramid, mongoengine, database

I've created a basic mongoengine app using the pyramid_mongodb scaffold...however I'd like to include mongoengine. I'm wondering what I should actually keep from the scaffolds code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a answer regarding the scaffold. I wouldn't recommend using the scaffold since it's not really usable for root_factory and so on, the subscribers isn't really needed too.

I wrote an addon for pyramid. It's called pyramid_mongo.

Documentation:

- http://packages.python.org/pyramid_mongo/

Github:

- https://github.com/llacroix/pyramid_mongo

I saw your question today and felt it could be a good addon to the plugin.

I just pushed it to github so you need to clone it from there for now, installing using pip will load the old version without support for mongoengine.

In other words in your config, do everything like in the docs and add something like:

```
mongo.mongoengine=true
```

It will attach mongo from the config to mongoengine. All other api will work with or without mongoengine and mongoengine should work. It just added it today, it doesn't support multiple connections and multiple dbs. I can also add support for multiple dbs too. But I feel mongoengine may do some things on his own that could conflict with my plugin like authorization.

Once I write tests, I'll push it to python packages and it will be possible to install from pip or easy_install. For now, pull it from github